# Convert packaged Atom Electron OSX app to IOS

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, mobile, electron

I have a relatively simple node application:
 - built on Electron
 - using an SQLite database
 - successfully packaged as a OSX application

Are there any tools out there for converting/re-packaging my Electron OSX app to iOS?
Am I correct in understanding that Phonegap is not a like-for-like replacement for Electron?

Cheers everyone/anyone!
Sam

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how deep your Electron app is bound to Electron specific API. Those specific API comprises Node and Electron functions. Those specific Electron functions (for example application menu) will be something you have to manually migrate. So the steps would be:

1. Create new Cordova app in iOS. Cordova web site has detailed instructions.
2. Copy your html/js/css content from Electron app and hook on Cordova bootstrapper
3. Replace Electron specific API to something pure web
4. Replace Node functions with possibly NPM analogous modules

Note:some Node API won't be available from Cordova app, for example file system API.

Comment: Thanks a million Eugene, I'll be looking into that Cordova bootstrapper next. Your comment on it depending how deep the app is bound to the electron API really got me thinking about what I was trying to achieve, and I'm now most likely going to develop a `localStorage` solution, as the mobile aspect of the app I'm building is for data capture only.
Cheers again, Sam